# How can I make this table bigger and centered, while still being on one page?

Tags: tables, width, sharelatex

Made this table excel and included it in sharelatex like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/reviewtable}
\caption{insert}
\label{fig:reviewtable}
\end{figure}
```

I would like the table to fill the page more for readability. However, if I increase the width, the table stops being centered, and eventually the right side of the table is pushed outside the page. Anyone got any tips? Tips on how to make the table in from scratch in latex, would also be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove the margins of the page where you put this table ?

Comment: How do I remove margins from a page in latex? I'm very new to latex..8)

Comment: You can save the excel table as PDF-file, filling a whole page, and include that page using the package `pdfpages`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\centering
\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{Figures/reviewtable}}
```

to make it 20% bigger, or whatever size fits within the margins.

Although do you really want to include this as an image? Why not just extract the text from excel and typeset the table in latex to be consistent with the rest of the document?